# Presto in Dataproc: configure a Kafka catalog

Tags: apache-kafka, presto, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to create a dataproc cluster with Presto as optional components and I would like to add a kafka catalog to it. Following https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/presto and https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka.html#configuration-properties I am using the following command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create mycluster \
    --region us-central1 \
    --no-address \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    --single-node \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --master-boot-disk-size 500 \
    --project myproject \
    --optional-components=PRESTO \
    --enable-component-gateway \
    --properties="presto-catalog:kafkastream.connector.name=kafka,presto-catalog:kafkastream.kafka.tables-names=topicname,presto-catalog:kafkastream.kafka.nodes=kafkavm:9092,presto-catalog:kafkastream.kafka.default-schema=default,presto-catalog:kafkastream.kafka.hide-internal-columns=false"
```

So, basically I want to set the `properties` to install catalog called `kafkastream` that connect to a kafka vm on port `9092` and creates a table `default.topicname`.

However, when I try to create the cluster the status goes to error. In the log I found something related with `StructuredError{presto, Component presto failed to activate`.
Other errors in the log are

```
google-dataproc-startup[1129]: activate-component-presto[2447]: Query 12345 failed: Presto server is still initializing
google-dataproc-startup[1129]: activate-component-presto[2447]: 'get_node_information' attempt 6 failed! Sleeping 10s.
google-dataproc-startup[1129]: activate-component-presto[2447]: Error running command: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8060
```

If I remove the `properties` part Presto works perfectly.

which is the right way to set a kafka catalog? Could someone helps me? I cannot found information related to this question neither in other stackoverflow topics nor online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--properties` feature for the optional component Presto seems to have a bug and it does not work as expected. However, I have found a way to set up a kafka catalog via an initialisation script `init-script.sh` in a GCS bucket:

```
#init-script.sh
function add_kafka-catalog() {
  cat > /etc/presto/conf/catalog/kafka.properties <<EOF
connector.name=kafka
kafka.nodes=my-vm:9092
kafka.table-names=my-topic
kafka.hide-internal-columns=false
EOF
}

# Restart presto to read new catalogs
function restart_presto() {
    sudo /usr/lib/presto/bin/launcher restart
}

function main() {
add_kafka-catalog
restart_presto
}
main
```

and launching the cluster via

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create mycluster \
    --region us-central1 \
    --no-address \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    --single-node \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --master-boot-disk-size 500 \
    --project myproject \
    --optional-components=PRESTO \
    --enable-component-gateway
    --initialization-actions 'gs://mybucket/init-script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the property name `kafka.tables-names`:

```
$ cat /var/log/presto/server.log | grep Exception -A 10

...
1) Error: Configuration property 'kafka.tables-names' was not used

1 error
    at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:238)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.kafka.KafkaConnectorFactory.create(KafkaConnectorFactory.java:73)
    at io.prestosql.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnector(ConnectorManager.java:349)
    at io.prestosql.connector.ConnectorManager.createCatalog(ConnectorManager.java:208)
    at io.prestosql.connector.ConnectorManager.createCatalog(ConnectorManager.java:200)
    at io.prestosql.connector.ConnectorManager.createCatalog(ConnectorManager.java:186)
```

It should be `kafka.table-names` (no `s` after `table`). You did it correctly in the init action, but wrong in the `--properties` flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't notice it